Not possible to increment the counter using set state in a simple recursive function in React
I understand that setState is asynchronous, but does it explicitly wait for all other code to be executed before it completes (even setTimeout with delay)?
I've been trying to increment a counter using a simple recursive function in React, but setState never executes. I added a setTimeout with a one-second delay, just to give setState enough time to execute, but it just keeps waiting infinitely and never executes.
Is replacing useState with useRef the best solution, or are there more elegant solutions?
import { useState } from 'react';

const TestComponent = () => {

const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

const setStateTest = () => {        
    setCounter(prev => prev + 1); // this line of code never executes
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (counter < 10) {
            setStateTest(); // this recursion happens infinitely because counter is never incremented
            console.log(counter); // the logged value is always 1, no incrementing
        }
    }, 1000)
}

return <button onClick={setStateTest}>Set State Test</button>

}


Don't use recursion for this.
I suspect the problem is a closure around the original counter value.  State itself may be getting updated, but you're not logging the current state to the console.  You're logging the captured value of that state when the function was first called.  (Click the button again and observe updated values being logged to the console, alongside the ongoing original value.)
Instead of recursing, rely on useEffect.  For example, consider this approach:
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(counter);
  const x = setTimeout(() => {
    setCounter(prev => prev + 1);
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearTimeout(x);
}, [counter]);

Any time counter changes, this effect will execute.  And all this effect does is:

Log the value of counter to the console
Set a timeout to update the value of counter in 1 second
Return a function to clear the timeout (this is important so that effects do not leak resources)

Then to initially trigger it, just update state once:
<button onClick={() => setCounter(prev => prev + 1)}>Set State Test</button>

Once this changes the state, the effect triggers and it perpetually re-triggers itself every second (by updating the state value in its dependency array) as long as the component is loaded.

States in React are asynchronous and the value will only update after the function has finished running. Since your function never stops running (as it loops the setTimeout), the asynchronous call never gets a chance to finish and update the state value, thus it remains at 1. For this reason, state is not the best way to do what you are currently trying to do. Define counter using let outside of the scope of TestComponent instead.

This is the only answer that I understand here, very good explanation

We shall start off discussing your question referring to the topic - Rendering takes a snapshot in time
As the documentation says, Rendering in React means calling your component which is a function. The JSX you return from that function is like a snapshot of the UI in time. This includes the event handlers which will be triggered on user interactions.
The most important point to note here is that these event handlers were calculated using its state at the time of the render. And the state is also a snapshot which remains unchanged within a render. And Setting state within an event does not change its value instantly, instead, it just queues up a new render which will begin only once the current event is over.
Now we shall come to your code:
a. On the first clicking, the value of the state within the event will be 1. And it will remain 1 throughout execution of the event.
b. Therefore the state counter does not change within the event which causes the recursive invocation of the function setStateTest non-terminating.
c. The snapshot nature of the state is the same even in the asynchronous code by setTimeout. That is why setTimeout does not improve the code.
By now it should be clarified that a recursive call cannot be done based on the state variable within an event. Therefore the code requires revision. The sample codes below may be one of the possible revisions.
The sample code includes  synchronous as well as asynchronous recursive function invocations.
The most notable point in either case is that the recursive invocation is controlled by a local variable passed as arguments to the function. Using snapshot state variables will lead to infinite calling as we have already discussed.
By running the sample code, on Clicking each button, the state will be added by 10.
App.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return <TestComponent />;
}

const TestComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

  const setStateTest = (localCounter = 1) => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
    if (localCounter < 10) {
      setStateTest(localCounter + 1);
    }
  };

  const setStateTestAsync = async (localCounter = 1) => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(() => {
      if (localCounter < 10) {
        setStateTestAsync(localCounter + 1);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      state value : {counter}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setStateTest()}>
        Set State Test synchronised
      </button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setStateTestAsync()}>
        Set State Test Asynchronised
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

Test run output
By loading the app, and then clicking on the sync button first.

By clicking the Async button followed by the first button click

Citation : Recursive async function in JavaScript
